# Django IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, django, apache, openstack, ioerror

In my Django view i have

```
 file = open('/files/req.json','w')
        file.write(json_data)
        file.close()
```

But when it is executed, I see following error in logs.

```
    file = open('/files/req.json','w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/files/req.json'
```

I have **chmod 777** on **/files** and **apache** as owner but error is still there. Following is the output of `ls -alh /files/`

```
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache 4.0K Apr  3 08:26 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root   root   4.0K Apr  3 08:26 ..
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache    0 Apr  3 08:26 req.json
```

I am on Fedora 20 x64 and using Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Are you sure that Django view is trying to write under apache user?

Comment: I don't know that what internet says. How can i find out the user ?

Comment: Who/How is running the python application?

Comment: Application is part of OpenStack-Horizon Project